# How to detect delimiter in temporary file?

Tags: php, file-upload, phpexcel, delimiter, tmp

CSV file uploaded, and saved as .tmp file in server's /tmp folder. Encountered problem to get its delimiter. It could be either ';' or ','. How I can check this from .tmp file? As I understand it can't be done with tmp file, so I need to save it as .csv and then check for delimiter. Is it the only way to do this?

Comment: The character which is not the delimiter can be inside the strings?

Comment: Do you mean ';' and ',' as strings? If yes, then only these characters can be present in strings

Comment: You can do anything with `.tmp` files as well as any other extension if its contents is proper CSV. You only need complete filename to open it.

Comment: Let's assume that `;` is the delimiter. Is it then possible, that your file contains something like this: `val1,something;val2` while `val1,something` should be detected as *one* value?

Comment: @MrPixelDream, in my case it cannot be

Comment: @Boog well, then there's a bad solution: replace all `,` and `;` to something you'll be sure in (`\t` for example). Then you'll be able to parse it like this `fgetcsv($h, 0, "\t");`.

Comment: @MrPixelDream please show specification for case of possible different delimiters!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, re-use an existing package of well-written, well-tested code ... such as "[CSV](http://csv.thephpleague.com/)" from [The League of Extraordinary Packages](https://thephpleague.com/).  Not only does CSV have a lot of goodness for working with CSV files, it has a function for determining what is the delimiter used in a CSV file.  For example:

```
use League\Csv\Reader;
$reader = Reader::createFromPath('/path/to/your/csv/file.csv');
$reader->setEnclosure('"');
$reader->setEscape('\\');
$delimiters_list = $reader->fetchDelimitersOccurrence([',',';','|'], 10);
```

This will look at the first 10 lines of the .csv file and count the occurrences of delimiters it finds.  If `$delimiters_list` is `[','=>40, ';'=>0, '|'=>0]` then you know it is a CSV file that consistently used `,` as its delimiter.

Other CSV pacakges can be found [HERE](https://packagist.org/search/?q=csv) in Packagist.org.